# How can I make my if-else statement work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My function takes an integer array of divisors, a `low` number and a `high` number as parameters. It prints the range between a `low` and a `high` number.

- If the number in the range is divisible by all elements of the array, print "all match".
- If at least one number matches, print "one match".
- If no number matches, print the number.

But, I can't figure out how to write my if-else statements properly. It only prints the numbers that match. When I change the else-if statement, it prints all the numbers twice.

```
function allFactors(factors, num){
          var nums = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
            var factor = factors[i];
            if(num % factor === 0){
              nums.push(factor);
            }
          }
          if(nums.length === factors.length){
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }

        //console.log(allFactors([2,3],6))

        function isFactor(num, factor) {
          if(num % factor === 0) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }

        function matches(factors, low, high) {
          var skipper = false
            for(var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
              if(allFactors(factors,i)){
                console.log(i + " match_all")
              } else {
              for(var j = 0; j < factors.length;j++) {
                var factor = factors[j];

                if(isFactor(i,factor)) {
                  console.log(i + " match_one");
                  skipper = true
                } else {
                  if(isFactor(i,factor)) {continue}
                  console.log(i)
                }
              }

              }
            }
        }


        matches([2,3],1,6)
```

Comment: what does this line `skipper = true` do?

Comment: i was thinking if i can make it true when the second if statement was true then i could get it not to print but it would still print

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking from the loops once you know that One factor matches.

```
function matches(factors, low, high) {    
    var skipper = false;

    for(var i = low; i <= high; i++) {

        if(allFactors(factors,i)){
            console.log(i + " match_all")
        } else {

            for(var j = 0; j < factors.length;j++) {
                var factor = factors[j];

                if(isFactor(i,factor)) {

                    console.log(i + " match_one");
                    skipper = true;

                    // break here because we know that at least one factor matches
                    // and print "match_one"
                    break;
                } else {

                    // number not matched
                    console.log(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // use skipper variable you assigned above to break out of outer loop
        if(skipper){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still no bueno only counts up to number 2 then returns d=for any set of numbers this question really is stumping me

Comment: check my edit, `if` statment around `continue;` is useless. You were checking `if( 5 > 7 ){ } else { if(5 > 7) { continue; } }`.